# How many tables do we need to represent patients and employees?

Tags: database-design

I was asked a newbie question about database design and I wonder if anyone can confirm is my answer right or not.

There are a medicine clinic with patients and employees. The patient has a card number and the employee has TaxPayerId. An employee can be a patient and vise versa. Both patients and employees have FirstName, LastName, BirthDate and PhoneNumber. The question was how many tables we need to represent this data structure and what alternatives can be? What are the benefits of different alternatives?

I was confused a bit by this question, and answered that we can use a single table (SQLite syntax):

```
CREATE TABLE Person (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    FirstName TEXT NOT NULL, LastName TEXT NOT NULL, 
    BirthDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, PhoneNumber INTEGER, 
    MedicineCardNumber INTEGER, TaxPayerId INTEGER);
```

As far as I see this table does not violate the rules of 3rd normal form, but I am not absolutely sure. At least, as far as I see, there is no transitive dependencies between non-key attributes, because the functional dependencies are: MedicineCardNumber->FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, PhoneNumber and TaxPayerId->FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, PhoneNumber. ID is a primary key that added by myself, there was no ID in the original task.

If this table is in 3rd normal form, what alternatives can be here? I feel that the person who asked the question expected more detailed answer.

Comment: The person who asked the question did not described any functional dependencies, but he called FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, PhoneNumber, MedicalCardNumber, TaxPayerId attributes. But also he mentioned that there should be some alternative solutions with their benefits and disadvantages. Any ideas on what he meant?

Comment: But you are answering the question and you must have determined FDs and done some other stuff in order to have an opinion that it is or isn't in any particular NF. If you don' t understand that then you need to go read about what these terms all mean.

Comment: Please edit your question, don't clarify in comments, they are ephemeral, and a post should be self-contained. If you have an opinion about NFs you should show/outline your justification too.

Comment: Suppose null was just another value. What would the CKs be? What is a solution with two tables? Surely you can see other designs? There is a classic 3-table design for supertype & 2 subtypes. PS 'Not absolutely sure' means 'don't know'. Learn normalization.

Comment: Cannot figure out, what reduction CKs is used for. At least the original question contained "what alternatives can be? Describe their benefits.".

Comment: Probably the alternatives are adding ID primary key and using natural primary key (MedicineCardNumber, TaxPayerId)? Figured out - CK is Candidate Key! So CK is (MedicineCardNumber, TaxPayerId).

Comment: Right, the combination of columns (MedicineCardNumber, TaxPayerId) cannot be used as primary key because it contains nulls (at least in MySQL), so is not my solution with the single table the best in this situation? Assuming a patient and employee do not have (and will not have) additional separate attributes.

Comment: The individual columns do *not* determine the others; they might be NULL. The pair CK/PK would work relationally.  But those 2 columns are NULLable, so you can't declare it an SQL PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL or reference it by an SQL FK. You can declare it UNIQUE, but that won't properly constrain it because all NULLs are "unique". Also any time you'd JOIN ON it you'd need IS NULL tests. One could use 2 boolean columns instead of NULLs. (Obscure.) Next: 2 & 3 tables.

Comment: You weren't asked for best. (Not that there is one without a lot more specifics including testing.) You were asked for pluses & minuses of various options. PS Please read my edited last comment. PPS Don't forget a person can be a patient & emp.

Comment: And even they the additional attributes will appear in future for the patient, for example, we will add a table with MedicineCardNumber primary key.